# Grok processor in ingest pattern adds escaped double quotes on save

Tags: elasticsearch, grok, ingest

Im using elastic "Stack management" -> "Ingest pipelines" -> "Edit pipeline".
In "Grok" processor fill fields "Pattern" with
`^%{MESSAGE}`
and "Pattern definitions (optional)" with

```
{
    "GREEDYDATA": "(.|\n|\t)*",
    "MESSAGE": "%{GREEDYDATA:message}"
}
```

After pressing "Update" i saw that saved json in "Pattern definitions (optional)" becomes like this:

```
{
    "GREEDYDATA": """(.|
|   )*""",
    "MESSAGE": "%{GREEDYDATA:message}"
}
```

And my pattern not working. Its must be valid for any text wihthout qoutes, but no.
In grok debug pattern works. Im tries escaping new lines and tabs, but it doesn't help. Why there quotes appears on save?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save your pattern by escaping the newline and tabulation characters, like this:

```
{
  "GREEDYDATA": "(.|\\n|\\t)*",
  "MESSAGE": "%{GREEDYDATA:message}"
}
```

After you save it, it will look like this

```
{
  "GREEDYDATA": """(.|\n|\t)*""",
  "MESSAGE": "%{GREEDYDATA:message}"
}
```

So instead of containing verbatim newline and tabulation characters, your pattern will contain `\n` and `\t` instead.

Comment: Sorry, im not clearly specified that already tried it, but it wont help. Problem is quotes that appears on save, and because of them pattern can be applied only to text with quotes. But not to any text as it was before save and in debug.

Comment: No the triple quotes are a specific Kibana feature to enclose special characters that cannot be enclosed in a single pair of double quotes, they are not introducing additional double quotes to be matched. You're safe